# How to write a generic function to sort a string array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, macros, generic-programming

I'm trying to write a generic function to sort different types of data. My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define GENERIC_SORT(TYPE) \
TYPE ##_SORT(TYPE a[],int n) \
{  \
int i,j; \
TYPE aux; \
for(i=1;i<n;i++) \
    for(j=n-1;j>=i;j--) \
    if(a[j]<a[j-1]) \
{ \
    aux=a[j]; \
    a[j]=a[j-1]; \
    a[j-1]=aux; \
} \
}
GENERIC_SORT(int)
GENERIC_SORT(float)
GENERIC_SORT(double)
GENERIC_SORT(char)
int main(void)
{
int i,a[]={3,7,5,4,6,1};
int_SORT(a,6);
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
return 0;
}
```

I'm preparing for an exam,and in the courses there's an example with `GENERIC_MAX`, which finds the maximum between 2 values. And I'm supposed to make the sort just like this...

It works fine on `int`, `float`, `double` and `char`. But how can I use it to sort a string array (`char a[][100]` or `char *a[]`)?

Comment: Why don't you use `qsort()`?

Comment: I'm preparing for an exam,and in the courses there's an example with GENERIC_MAX,which finds the maximum between 2 values. And I'm supposed to make the sort just like this...

Comment: should it be a macro? you could mimic `qsort()` and use a callback function.

Answer (score 5):

A prime example of a generic sort is the C runtime library `qsort()`.  One of its most versatile attributes is that it makes use of a "comparison function" which is passed as a parameter.

Why not adopt that tactic?  While it is true that most comparison functions are trivial, in the case of accessing objects it is invaluable for interpreting what is inside the object.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is generate the C equivalent of C++'s template functions using generics. This is usually a combination of function pointers and re-casting `void*` data to achieve the desired result. The `qsort()` function does just this. Included below is a code listing and sample run [from a similar answer of mine from some time back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662383/sorting-structures-basis-of-any-structure-element/27662526#27662526) that shows you how to use a simple Bubble Sort implementation for multiple data types.

To extend this to any data type, you just need to:

1. Create your own `int compareDataType(void* a, void* b)` function
2. Update the `sizeOfElement` and `compareFcn` parameters passed to the `BubbleSort()` function.

Your approach might work for primitive data types that already have defined comparison operations, but it won't work for abstract data types likes `struct`s, etc.

**Code Listing**

---

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Preprocessor Directives
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>   // printf
#include <stdlib.h>  // calloc
#include <string.h>  // memcpy
#include <time.h>    // random seed initialization
#define ELEMENT_AT(arr, i, w) (((char*)arr) + ((i)*(w)))
#define BUF_SIZE  (20)


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/
typedef struct cricket_s {
   char pname[BUF_SIZE];
   char tname[BUF_SIZE];
   int avg;
} cricket_t;


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/
/* @functionName: bubbleSort
 * @brief:        Performs a bubble sort on an input array, using a user-
 *                provided function pointer for comparing data types so that
 *                the function can be as generic as possible.
 * @param:        arr: The array to search.
 * @param:        compareFcn: The comparison function to use.
 * @param:        sizeOfElement: The size of a single element in arr
 * @param:        numElements: The number of elements in arr
 */
void* bubbleSort(void* arr, int (*compareFcn)(void*, void*), size_t sizeOfElement, size_t numElements);

void rand_str(char *dest, size_t length);
int compareCricketAvg(void *a, void *b);
int compareCricketPname(void *a, void *b);

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void* bubbleSort(void* arr, int (*compareFcn)(void*, void*), size_t sizeOfElement, size_t numElements) {
   if (!arr || !compareFcn || !numElements || !sizeOfElement) {
      return NULL;
   }
   int i, j;
   void* tempBuf;
   /* Create a swap buffer */
   if ((tempBuf = calloc(1, sizeOfElement)) == NULL) {
      return NULL;
   }
   /* Sort the list via bubble sort (stable) */
   for (i=0; i<(numElements-1); i++) {
      for (j=0; j<(numElements - i -1); j++) {
         if (compareFcn(ELEMENT_AT(arr, j, sizeOfElement), ELEMENT_AT(arr, j+1, sizeOfElement)) == (-1)) {
            memcpy(tempBuf, ELEMENT_AT(arr, j, sizeOfElement), sizeOfElement);
            memcpy(ELEMENT_AT(arr, j, sizeOfElement), ELEMENT_AT(arr, j+1, sizeOfElement), sizeOfElement);
            memcpy(ELEMENT_AT(arr, j+1, sizeOfElement), tempBuf, sizeOfElement);
         }
      }
   }
   /* Clean up and exit */
   free(tempBuf);
   return arr;
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Comparson function s.
 * Returns (-1) if a<b, +1 if a>b, 0 if a==b
 */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int compareCricketAvg(void *a, void *b) {
   if (!a || !b) {
      /* Treat bad input as equality */
      return 0;
   }
   int ret;
   if (((cricket_t*)a)->avg < ((cricket_t*)b)->avg) {
      ret = (-1);
   } else if (((cricket_t*)a)->avg > ((cricket_t*)b)->avg) {
      ret = 1;
   } else
      ret = 0;
   return ret;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int compareCricketPname(void *a, void *b) {
   if (!a || !b) {
      /* Treat bad input as equality */
      return 0;
   }
   int ret;
   char *s1, *s2;
   s1 = ((cricket_t*)a)->pname;
   s2 = ((cricket_t*)b)->pname;
   ret = strncmp(s1, s2, BUF_SIZE);
   if (ret > 0) {
      ret = 1;
   } else if (ret < 0) {
      ret = (-1);
   } else {
      ret = 0;
   }

   return ret;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void rand_str(char *dest, size_t length) {
    char charset[] = "0123456789"
                     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    while (length-- > 0) {
        size_t index = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX * (sizeof charset - 1);
        *dest++ = charset[index];
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Main Entry Point
 ******************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(void) {
   srand(time(NULL));   // init random seed
   int numPlayers = 10;
   int i;

   /* Dynamically allocate memory for a few teams */
   cricket_t* team;
   if ((team = calloc(numPlayers, sizeof(cricket_t))) == NULL) {
      printf("Memory error\n");
      return (-1);
   }

   /* Populate struct values */
   for (i=0; i<numPlayers; i++) {
      team[i].avg = rand() % 1000;
      rand_str(team[i].pname, BUF_SIZE);
      printf("Team %d - Pname:%s - Average:%d\n", i, team[i].pname, team[i].avg);
   }
   printf("\n");

   /* Sort the list according to AVG value */
   bubbleSort((void*)team, compareCricketAvg, sizeof(cricket_t), numPlayers);

   /* Print sorted team */
   for (i=0; i<numPlayers; i++) {
      printf("Team %d - Pname:%s - Average:%d\n", i, team[i].pname, team[i].avg);
   }
   printf("\n");

   /* Sort again, now by pname */
   bubbleSort((void*)team, compareCricketPname, sizeof(cricket_t), numPlayers);

   /* Print sorted team */
   for (i=0; i<numPlayers; i++) {
      printf("Team %d - Pname:%s - Average:%d\n", i, team[i].pname, team[i].avg);
   }
   printf("\n");

   free(team);
   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run**

---

```
Team 0 - Pname:YY7plBOnjIi7YQTKjgqB - Average:605
Team 1 - Pname:sKGbl8pIAjHzq6U2UimD - Average:439
Team 2 - Pname:tBrmmKDNmvf6crrlQaWa - Average:226
Team 3 - Pname:vBXqESI0vju7KRuvvhS1 - Average:117
Team 4 - Pname:YdYqzPBv0s0Bqqgi9hNs - Average:209
Team 5 - Pname:VdDpJ8GB9dAnb0W1Bs14 - Average:633
Team 6 - Pname:DuUTM3bAvXvJAVsJB3TP - Average:212
Team 7 - Pname:h1Fd2hF3l8GQ2AD6LdBI - Average:237
Team 8 - Pname:kjEN3gRX5ve6ar8r7cMg - Average:467
Team 9 - Pname:Djtgpet1XdmhSal81iew - Average:473

Team 0 - Pname:VdDpJ8GB9dAnb0W1Bs14 - Average:633
Team 1 - Pname:YY7plBOnjIi7YQTKjgqB - Average:605
Team 2 - Pname:Djtgpet1XdmhSal81iew - Average:473
Team 3 - Pname:kjEN3gRX5ve6ar8r7cMg - Average:467
Team 4 - Pname:sKGbl8pIAjHzq6U2UimD - Average:439
Team 5 - Pname:h1Fd2hF3l8GQ2AD6LdBI - Average:237
Team 6 - Pname:tBrmmKDNmvf6crrlQaWa - Average:226
Team 7 - Pname:DuUTM3bAvXvJAVsJB3TP - Average:212
Team 8 - Pname:YdYqzPBv0s0Bqqgi9hNs - Average:209
Team 9 - Pname:vBXqESI0vju7KRuvvhS1 - Average:117

Team 0 - Pname:vBXqESI0vju7KRuvvhS1 - Average:117
Team 1 - Pname:tBrmmKDNmvf6crrlQaWa - Average:226
Team 2 - Pname:sKGbl8pIAjHzq6U2UimD - Average:439
Team 3 - Pname:kjEN3gRX5ve6ar8r7cMg - Average:467
Team 4 - Pname:h1Fd2hF3l8GQ2AD6LdBI - Average:237
Team 5 - Pname:YdYqzPBv0s0Bqqgi9hNs - Average:209
Team 6 - Pname:YY7plBOnjIi7YQTKjgqB - Average:605
Team 7 - Pname:VdDpJ8GB9dAnb0W1Bs14 - Average:633
Team 8 - Pname:DuUTM3bAvXvJAVsJB3TP - Average:212
Team 9 - Pname:Djtgpet1XdmhSal81iew - Average:473
```

Comment: `functionName: binarySearch`: copy-paste typo?

Answer (score 2):

You can circumvent the problem of non-symbol types like `char *` or `struct point` by defining new types with `typedef`. A better approach may be to pass the name of the new function to the macro as additional parameter.

The problem of the comparison can be solved by passing the comparison criterion, as in the callback function of `qsort` that others have pointed you to. Because the function is not really called, but substituted at compile time, it can be a macro.

Here's your macro extended:

```
#define GENERIC_SORT(NAME, TYPE, LT)            \
    void NAME(TYPE a[], int n)                  \
    {                                           \
        int i, j;                               \
                                                \
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {               \
            for (j = n - 1; j >= i; j--) {      \
                if (LT(a[j], a[j - 1])) {       \
                    TYPE aux = a[j];            \
                    a[j] = a[j - 1];            \
                    a[j - 1] = aux;             \
                }                               \
            }                                   \
        }                                       \
    }
```

Your integer sort is then:

```
#define LESS(a, b) ((a) < (b))

GENERIC_SORT(int_sort, int, LESS);

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {
        6, 3, 9, 2, 7, 10, 5, 1
    };
    int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    int i;

    int_sort(array, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sort strings with a comparison function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "gen.h"   /* your macro */

int str_less(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
}

GENERIC_SORT(str_sort, const char *, str_less);

int main(void)
{
    const char *array[] = {
        "apricot", "orange", "banana", "apple", "papaya", "kiwi"
    };
    int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    int i;

    str_sort(array, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `GENERIC_MAX` code (as described in a comment), you can use it instead of comparing and swapping. To do it, define `GENERIC_MIN` (should be easy - very similar to generic max). Then:

```
#define GENERIC_SORT(TYPE) \
TYPE ##_SORT(TYPE a[],int n) \
{  \
int i,j; \
TYPE aux_min, aux_max; \
for(i=1;i<n;i++) \
    for(j=n-1;j>=i;j--) \
{ \
    aux_min=GENERIC_MIN(a[j], a[j-1]); \
    aux_max=GENERIC_MAX(a[j], a[j-1]); \
    a[j-1]=aux_min; \
    a[j]=aux_max; \
} \
}
```